# When should I use implicit casting?

Tags: c#, .net, casting

When is it safe to use implicit casting?

**Use Case**: I'm working with a set of com objects that need to be taken care of specially (Marshal.ReleaseComObject).  Is it OK to create a wrapper class that implicitly converts back to the actual com object wrapped?

What are some situations when I *shouldn't* use implicit casting?

Comment: Just to be picky: there is no such thing as "implicit casting". You can use a *cast operator* to tell the compiler to perform an *explicit conversion*, or you can omit the cast operator and perform an *implicit conversion*, but there is no *implicit cast*. The *cast* is the thing that appears in the source code; if it doesn't appear there then there is no *cast*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to perform this cast a lot.
2. There isn't a way to avoid the cast.
3. It's not better represented as a conversion/projection function.  To put it another way, it's got to be "the same object" after the cast.
4. You can round-trip to the original object.  (Not implicitly, though.)
5. It's not going to mess with existing or possible future function overloads.

I usually summarize these points as "never", but ironically your use case actually sounds like a goer...

Answer (score 3):

You should use implicit casting when (and only when) you are sure that:
 1. No information (data) is lost (or can be lost) while converting.
 2. No exception can be thrown.
 3. No silent fail can occur (you will receive degenerated data).